# What is the reserve_size parameter in getblocktemplate?

Tags: rpc, daemon, getblocktemplate

The [`getblocktemplate` RPC method](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/daemon-rpc#getblocktemplate) accepts a parameter, `reserve_size`. What does it do and what are its valid values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reserve_size is the amount of data to reserve in the block template for the extra nonce (arbitrary data which may be embedded in a transaction). The maximum amount is 255 bytes. This is used by the pool code to place a nonce which will be incremented to try to find a block hash below the current difficulty target.